# Filter records from the dataset in vb.net

Tags: dataset, vb.net-2010, rowfilter

I want to **filter values from a dataset**. It contain phone numbers *starting with zero and non zero values*. How can I filter a phone number (start with non zero no) from the dataset. Below is the vb.net code and the resulting error.

```
cmd = New OracleCommand("select  PHONE from  reports.renewal_contact_t where run_date=to_date('" + TextBox1.Text + "','mm/dd/yyyy') and  EXP_DATE =to_date('" + TextBox2.Text + "','mm/dd/yyyy') and  region not in('TNP')", cn)
ada = New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
ada.Fill(ds, "reports.renewal_contact_t ")
Dim ds1 As New DataSet
ds1.Tables("reports.renewal_contact_t").DefaultView.RowFilter = "PHONE NOT like'0'"
```

**Error:** Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error in rowfilter line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your ds1 there is **no table** *reports.renewal_contact_t*.  Change it to

```
cmd = New OracleCommand("select  PHONE from  reports.renewal_contact_t where run_date=to_date('" + TextBox1.Text + "','mm/dd/yyyy') and  EXP_DATE =to_date('" + TextBox2.Text + "','mm/dd/yyyy') and  region not in('TNP')", cn)
ada = New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
ada.Fill(ds, "reports.renewal_contact_t")
' no need for a new dataset - as you fill ds (and not ds1)!!
ds.Tables("reports.renewal_contact_t").DefaultView.RowFilter = "PHONE NOT like'0'"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work against a dataset with a 'schema' similar to

**data example>*

```
Id   Value

1    303-888-8888
2    0-418-895-9598

TryCast(filteredDS.Tables(0).Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Where(Function(row) Not row.ItemArray(1).ToString().Substring(0, 1).Equals("0")), IEnumerable(Of DataRow)).ToList().ForEach(Sub(row) row.Delete())
```

--removes any record where the phone starts with anything other than a zero

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim indexTable As Integer = ds.Tables.Count - 1 ' ultima tabla dentro del dataSet
Dim tmpTable = ds.Tables(indexTable) ' copias la tabla del dataset

tmpTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "PHONE NOT like'0'" ' filtrar los datos de la temporal
ds.Tables.RemoveAt(indexTable) ' eliminas los datos sin filtrar
ds.Tables.Add(tmpTable.DefaultView.ToTable) ' agrega los datos filtrados de la temporal
ds.AcceptChanges() ' aceptas los cambios
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).